# align* environment left-aligned with LuaTeX and RTL math direction

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath, luatex, align, right-to-left

When using LuaLaTeX, with the math direction set right-to-left, the contents of an `align*` environment is left-aligned instead of centered. Why does this happens? How can I fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\luatexmathdir TRT
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
1+2=3
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
1+2&=3\nonumber\\
4+5&=6
\end{align}

\begin{align*}
1+2&=3\\
4+5&=6
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

**Update:** A similar problem, but this time LTR math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\luatexpagedir TRT
\luatexbodydir TRT
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
1+2=3
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
1+2&=3\nonumber\\
4+5&=6
\end{align}

\begin{align*}
1+2&=3\\
4+5&=6
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I was only interested in the second case as I never really typeset RTL math or need to implement it; it was good if `\pagedir` and `\bodydir` primitives had no effect in math mode (I am not sure to call that a bug or a feature). Anyway, I guess I am better off to not use `\bodydir` and `\pagedir` primitives. They are more problematic than being useful.

Another issue exits with `multline` environment used together with `fleqn` option:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}
\luatexpagedir TRT
\luatexbodydir TRT
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
1+2=3
\end{equation}
\begin{multline}
a+b+c+d+e+f\\
+i+j+k+l+m+n
\end{multline}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

This produces wrong margin; to fix it we simply use `\z@skip` for `\tabskip` instead `\@mathmargin`:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}
\luatexpagedir TRT
\luatexbodydir TRT
\makeatletter
\def\multline@#1{%
    \Let@
    \@display@init{\global\advance\row@\@ne \global\dspbrk@lvl\m@ne}%
    \chardef\dspbrk@context\z@
    \restore@math@cr
    \let\tag\tag@in@align
    \global\tag@false \global\let\raise@tag\@empty
    \mmeasure@{#1}%
    \let\tag\gobble@tag \let\label\@gobble
%    \tabskip \if@fleqn \@mathmargin \else \z@skip \fi
   \tabskip \z@skip
    \totwidth@\displaywidth
    \if@fleqn
        \advance\totwidth@-\@mathmargin
    \fi
    \halign\bgroup
        \hbox to\totwidth@{%
            \if@fleqn
                \hskip \@centering \relax
            \else
                \hfil
            \fi
            \strut@
            $\m@th\displaystyle{}##\endmultline@math
            \hfil
        }%
        \crcr
        \if@fleqn
            \hskip-\@mathmargin
            \def\multline@indent{\hskip\@mathmargin}% put it back
        \else
            \hfilneg
            \def\multline@indent{\hskip\multlinegap}%
        \fi
        \iftagsleft@
            \iftag@
                \begingroup
                    \ifshifttag@
                        \rlap{\vbox{%
                                \normalbaselines
                                \hbox{%
                                    \strut@
                                    \make@display@tag
                                }%
                                \vbox to\lineht@{}%
                                \raise@tag
                        }}%
                        \multline@indent
                    \else
                        \setbox\z@\hbox{\make@display@tag}%
                        \dimen@\@mathmargin \advance\dimen@-\wd\z@
                        \ifdim\dimen@<\multlinetaggap
                          \dimen@\multlinetaggap
                        \fi
                        \box\z@ \hskip\dimen@\relax
                    \fi
                \endgroup
            \else
                \multline@indent
            \fi
        \else
            \multline@indent
        \fi
    #1%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
1+2=3
\end{equation}
\begin{multline}
a+b+c+d+e+f\\
+i+j+k+l+m+n
\end{multline}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution puts `\place@tag` for `align*` environment where `\iftag@` is false. This way all as far as I tested work fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\luatexmathdir TRT
\makeatletter
\def\math@cr@@@align{%
  \ifst@rred\nonumber\fi
  \if@eqnsw \global\tag@true \fi
  \global\advance\row@\@ne
  \add@amps\maxfields@
  \omit
  \kern-\alignsep@
%  \iftag@
%    \setboxz@h{\@lign\strut@{\make@display@tag}}%
%    \place@tag
%  \fi
  \iftag@
    \setboxz@h{\@lign\strut@{\make@display@tag}}%
    \place@tag
  \else
    \place@tag
  \fi
  \ifst@rred\else\global\@eqnswtrue\fi
  \global\lineht@\z@
  \cr
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
1+2=3
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
1+2&=3\nonumber\\
4+5&=6
\end{align}

\begin{align*}
1+2&=3\\
4+5&=6
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add a description of the solution?

Comment: @egreg: Looks like he copied a definition from some distribution source files, then commented-out a few lines. An explanation would be nice, as would be some sort of assurance this commenting-out doesn't break other use cases (I would guess it does...)

Comment: the code for `\def\math@cr@@@align` is pulled directly from `amsmath.sty`, and the commented `\if` block replaced by the `\if` block below it.  a problem, also present in the original: the parentheses on the tags are facing outward, and a little experimentation shows that parens in the math itself are also; this indicates that they (and probably other fences) aren't handled properly.  however, `amsmath` has, to the best of my knowledge, never really been tested in a right-to-left environment, and many other adjustments would be needed to use it there reliably.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: The problem with parentheses is not `amsmath` problem; it is natural that in a right to left mode, the parentheses on the tags are facing outward. I have been testing not only `amsmath` but also `breqn`, `empheq` and many other math packages and I have adapted them for right to left (see my `bidi` package). For instance see this output of `empheq` produced by `xepersian` (in Persian, text is bidi and math is LTR): http://www.parsilatex.com/joomla/attachments/article/114/align-boxed.pdf

Comment: @VafaKhalighi -- thanks for the information.  while i agree that it's not something that `amsmath` should be "fixing", i do think it's important to note that there hasn't been testing *at ams* of r-to-l use.  i will definitely look at the source you've linked.  and if you find anything in `amsmath` that's a show-stopper for r-to-l processing (our list of bugs is long), please get in touch off-line.