# LuaTeX \bodydir and \pagedir: is there a way to switch them back from TRT to TLT?

Tags: lists, luatex, right-to-left

So far, I haven't found a way to have the standard list environments correctly indented under LuaTeX in right-to-left mode without using both of the `\bodydir` and `\pagedir` primitives, like so:—

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\bodydir TRT
\pagedir TRT
desserts.\footnote{Would you have any?}
\begin{enumerate}
\pardir TRT
\textdir TRT
\item desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
  desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
  desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
  desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
  desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
  desserts desserts.
  \item desserts.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
      desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
      desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
      desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
      desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
      desserts desserts desserts desserts.
      \begin{itemize}
      \item desserts.
      \end{itemize}
    \item desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
      desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
      desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
      desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
      desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
      desserts desserts desserts.
    \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}

% \bodydir TLT
% \pagedir TLT
\pardir TLT
\textdir TLT
desserts.\footnote{Would you have any?}

\end{document}
```

Note that both `\bodydir` and `\pagedir` have to be set outside the list environment; otherwise the indentation appears on the left side, which is wrong.

The problem is that I get into trouble when I try to set `\bodydir` and `\pagedir` back to `TLT`.

As for the above mwe, it compiles fine, but the footnote rule is flushed right while I would like to have it flushed left.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So far, I haven't found a way to have the standard list environments correctly indented under LuaTeX in right-to-left mode without using both of the \bodydir and \textdir primitives, like so:—

You meant `\pagedir` not `\textdir`?

LuaTeX's bidi model has too many bugs so it is much better to forget `\pagedir` and `\bodydir` and just work with `\pardir` and `\textdir`.

This is taken (almost) verbatim from the `bidi` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\def\list#1#2{%
  \ifnum \@listdepth >5\relax
    \@toodeep
  \else
    \global\advance\@listdepth\@ne
  \fi
  \rightmargin\z@
  \listparindent\z@
  \itemindent\z@
  \csname @list\romannumeral\the\@listdepth\endcsname
  \def\@itemlabel{#1}%
  \let\makelabel\@mklab
  \@nmbrlistfalse
  #2\relax
  \@trivlist
  \parskip\parsep
  \parindent\listparindent
  \advance\linewidth -\rightmargin
  \advance\linewidth -\leftmargin
  \advance\@totalleftmargin \rightmargin
  \parshape \@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth
  \ignorespaces}

\def\itemize{%
  \ifnum \@itemdepth >\thr@@\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \edef\@itemitem{labelitem\romannumeral\the\@itemdepth}%
    \expandafter
    \list
      \csname\@itemitem\endcsname
      {\def\makelabel##1{\llap{##1}\hss}}%
  \fi}

\def\@item[#1]{%
  \if@noparitem
    \@donoparitem
  \else
    \if@inlabel
      \indent \par
    \fi
    \ifhmode
      \unskip\unskip \par
    \fi
    \if@newlist
      \if@nobreak
        \@nbitem
      \else
        \addpenalty\@beginparpenalty
        \addvspace\@topsep
        \addvspace{-\parskip}%
      \fi
    \else
      \addpenalty\@itempenalty
      \addvspace\itemsep
    \fi
    \global\@inlabeltrue
  \fi
  \everypar{%
    \@minipagefalse
    \global\@newlistfalse
    \if@inlabel
      \global\@inlabelfalse
      {\setbox\z@\lastbox
       \ifvoid\z@
         \kern-\itemindent
       \fi}%
      \box\@labels
      \penalty\z@
    \fi
    \if@nobreak
      \@nobreakfalse
      \clubpenalty \@M
    \else
      \clubpenalty \@clubpenalty
      \everypar{}%
    \fi}%
  \if@noitemarg
    \@noitemargfalse
    \if@nmbrlist
      \refstepcounter\@listctr
    \fi
  \fi
  \sRTLbox\@tempboxa{\makelabel{#1}}%
  \global\setbox\@labels\hbox dir TRT{%
    \unhbox\@labels
    \hskip \itemindent
    \hskip -\labelwidth
    \hskip -\labelsep
    \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\labelwidth
      \box\@tempboxa
    \else
      \hbox to\labelwidth {\unhbox\@tempboxa}%
    \fi
    \hskip \labelsep}%
  \ignorespaces}

\def\itemize{%
  \ifnum \@itemdepth >\thr@@\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \edef\@itemitem{labelitem\romannumeral\the\@itemdepth}%
    \expandafter
    \list
      \csname\@itemitem\endcsname
      {\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}%
  \fi}

\long\def\sRTLbox#1#2{\setbox#1\hbox dir TRT{%
  \color@setgroup#2\color@endgroup}}
\makeatother
\pardir TRT
\textdir TRT
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
desserts.\footnote{Would you have any?}
\begin{enumerate}
\item desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
  desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
  desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
  desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
  desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
  desserts desserts.
  \item desserts.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
      desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
      desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
      desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
      desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
      desserts desserts desserts desserts.
      \begin{itemize}
      \item desserts.
      \end{itemize}
    \item desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
      desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
      desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
      desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
      desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts desserts
      desserts desserts desserts.
    \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
desserts.\footnote{Would you have any?}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I meant `\pagedir`. Many thanks for your answer: I'll run some tests with this code right away.

Comment: Thank you very much @user118241.  This works.  By the way, is it _known for a fact_ that `\bodydir` and `\pagedir` have bugs? Both primitives are hardly documented as far as I know.  Can anybody shed some light on this?

Comment: @RobertAlessi: Not just `\bodydir` and `\pagedir` but the whole LuaTeX's bidi model has too many bugs. Even if you look at ConTeXt sources, they also do not use `\bodydir` and `\pagedir` (just `\pardir` and `\textdir`).

Comment: thanks again, I'll look into this carefully.  For the time being I'll implement the code you've adapted from the `bidi` package. From this page though: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Arabic_and_Hebrew one can see that `\bodydir` and `\pagedir` are recommended.  But it dates back to 2010!

Comment: So far, I've never had a chance to use `\bodydir` and `\pagedir` in `arabluatex`; just `\pardir` and `\textdir`. I'll be careful to stay away from `\body/pagedir`. You've been very helpful, @user118241, thanks again.

Comment: @RobertAlessi For an example of how ugly LuaTeX's bidi model is, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134061

Comment: @RobertAlessi: For ConTeXt, please see the comment in file `spac-ali.mkiv`: https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/236690a6367b25187d37013e1e7fc196c5c44eb8/tex/context/base/mkiv/spac-ali.mkiv

Comment: Great! Many thanks for pointing me to these directions, @user118241. Having a working solution is good _per se_ but having a chance to increase one's erudition is so much better!

Comment: I strongly disagree with the idea that LuaTeX bidi model is ugly. I'm currently working with `babel` bidi and LuaTeX is a lot easier and more powerful than XeTeX o pdfTeX (in fact some features like mixed L/R modes with `bidi=basic-r`, and support for AL text will be available only in LuaTeX, sadly).

Comment: @JavierBezos You have no experience or expertise in the area of bidi TeX development so I took your words with a grain of salt.