# Issue with align* environment in TRT pagedir (lualatex)

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, luatex, amsmath, right-to-left

I have this example with `align*` environment in TRT pagedir (lualatex engine), The result is aligned to the right even though the environment is placed in  left to right context (with `\bodydir TLT \pardir TLT \textdir TLT`) @DavidCarlisle

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\pagedir TRT\bodydir TRT \pardir TRT \textdir TRT
\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
f(x)&=1+\dfrac{1}{x+2}\\
    &=1+k(x+2) 
\end{align*}

{%
\bodydir TLT \pardir TLT \textdir TLT
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=1+\dfrac{1}{x+2}\\
    &=1+k(x+2) 
\end{align*}
 }

 \newpage

\pagedir TLT \bodydir TLT \pardir TLT \textdir TLT

\begin{align*}
f(x)&=1+\dfrac{1}{x+2}\\
    &=1+k(x+2) 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Too complex for just a comment, but:

I just discovered that this problem has been addressed already [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134201/47927). I refined this solution by using the `etoolbox` package to patch the command instead of copying the whole definition of the relevant macro. Why exactly this patch works, however, is not fully clear to me, to be honest.

Since I only refined their answer and do not understand the mechanism behind it, credit should really be given to [user22486](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134201/47927).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\math@cr@@@align}{\fi\ifst@rred}{\else\place@tag\fi\ifst@rred}{}{}
\makeatother

\pagedir TRT \bodydir TRT \pardir TRT \textdir TRT

\begin{document}

Hello

\begin{align*}
f(x)&=1+\dfrac{1}{x+2}\\
    &=1+k(x+2) 
\end{align*}

Hello

{
\bodydir TLT \pardir TLT \textdir TLT 

Hello

\begin{align*}
f(x)&=1+\dfrac{1}{x+2}\\
    &=1+k(x+2) 
\end{align*}

Hello

}

Hello

\end{document}
```

[image]